# how to get items object from array and use it in another function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i would like to ask a solution for my react project component

> const handleGenerateBarcode = (e, item, detailID, qty) => {
> e.preventDefault();
> let details = transformationDetails;
>
> const transformationDetailID = item?.transformationDetailBarcode.filter((obj) =>obj.transformationDetailId === item.id)
>
> console.log("transformationDetailID", transformationDetailID)
>
> const transformationDetail = transformationDetails.filter((detail) => detail.id === item.id);
> console.log("transformationDetail", transformationDetail)
>
> setBarcode(transformationDetailID);
> setShowModal(true);
> };
>
> const renderBarcodeModal = () => {
> return (
>
>
>
> <div className="modal-header d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style={{ backgroundColor: "#3A936C", color: "white" }}>
>
> Barcode
>
>
>
> {barcode.map((item, index) => {
> return (
>
> <div className="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center flex-column" style={{ color: "black", marginBottom: '20px' }}>
> <img src={`https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chl=${`${item.itemId}-${index}`}&chs=250x250`} id="barcode" alt="Barcode" style={{ width: "100%" }} />
>
> {workOrderNo}/{items?.code}/{item.itemId}/({index + 1})
>
>
>
> );
> })}
>
>
>
> <div className="btn btn-secondary mt-2" data-dismiss="modal" style={{ backgroundColor: "white", color: "#498B71" }} id="close_modal">
> Close
>
> <div className="btn btn-primary mt-2" style={{ marginLeft: '40px' }} onClick={handleDownloadQR}>
>  Download
>
> <div className="d-flex flex-row" style={{ marginLeft: '30px' }}>
> {reactToPrintTrigger()}
>
>
>
>
>
>
> );
> };

> how do i map transformationDetails array in my handleGenerateBarcode to get the code params from the items object inside the array then how do i use it into my renderBarcodeModal function for the {items.code} label

Comment: can you make your code readable (use the `{}` button and remove all those `>`)

Comment: The code shared is not readable. Please review the formatting